# Zend Form Element with Javascript - Decorator, View Helper or View Script?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I want to add some javacsript to a Zend_Form_Element_Text .

At first I thought a decorator would be the best way to do it, but since it is just a script (the markup doesn't change) then maybe a view helper is better? or a view script?

It seems like they are all for the same purpose (regarding a form element).

The javascript I want to add is not an event (e.g. change, click, etc.). I can add it easily with headScript() but I want to make it re-usable , that's why I thought about a decorator/view helper. I'm just not clear about the difference between them.

What is the best practice in this case? advantages?

UPDATE: Seems like the best practice is to use view helpers from view scripts , so decorators would be a better fit?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. What js would you put in an element that isn't linked by an event ? I understand that you are trying to make something reusable, and a decorator is the best for it. But a decorator would add something before, after ou around the field, not IN the field. are you wanting to put some js in a `<script>` tag right after your `<input..` ?

Comment: it's a jquery snippet that will init the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own decorator by extending `Zend_From_Decorator_Abstract` and generate your snippet in it's `render()` method :

```
class My_Decorator_FieldInitializer extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract {
    public function render($content){

        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        $element = $this->getElement();

        $output = '<script>'.
             //you write your js snippet here, using 
             //the data you have in $element if you need 
             .'</script>';

        return $content . $separator . $output;
    }
}
```

If you need more details, ask for it in a comment, i'll edit this answer. And I didn't test this code.

Answer (score 2):

Use setAttrib function.

eg:-

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('test');
$element->setAttrib('onclick', 'alert("Test")');
```

Comment: My javascript code isn't an event, it will be in the head script, but I want to make it as decorator/view helper so it will be re-usable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not actually seeing where this needs to be a decorator or a view-helper or a view-script.

If I wanted to attach some client-side behavior to a form element, I'd probably set an attribute with `$elt->setAttrib('class', 'someClass')` or `$elt->setAttrib('id', 'someId')`, some hook onto which my script can attach. Then I'd add listeners/handlers to those targeted elements.

For example, for a click handler using jQuery , it would be something like:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.someClass').click(function(e){
            // handle the event here
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The benefit is that it is unobtrusive, so the markup remains clean. Hopefully, the javascript is an enhancement- not a critical part of the functionality - so it degrades gracefully.

Perhaps you mean that this javascript segment itself needs to be reusable across different element identifiers - `someClass`, in this example. In this case, you could simply write a view-helper that accepts the CSS class name as the parameter.

Comment: the point is that I have a component I wrote which is zend object and a javascript. I want to give it to other developers in my team to use, so I want to it to take care of the script by itself..

Comment: Based upon your accepted answer, I see now what you mean. Glad you found a solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

"the markup doesn't change", Yap,

but I like to add some javascript function throw ZendForm Element:

```
$text_f = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("text_id");
$text_f->setAttrib('OnChange', 'someFunction($(this));');
```

The best way is if you are working with a team, where all of you should use same code standard. For me and my team this is the code above.