# Three columns table Form in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I have some problem to create "three columns table" form in Zend Framework:

I already have Zend Form  decorated by tow columns table:

Table have two column, first one is for label and second one is for Zend_Form_Element, that works well, but,
I want to add third column and put there small image - question mark, where I will setup javascript.

How to set decoration for that?

Current decoration for two columns table is:

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {

    // create decoration for form's elements
    $elementDecoration = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'valign' => 'TOP')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Errors'),
        array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
    );
    $buttonDecoration = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('data'  => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
        array(array('label' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
        array(array('row'   => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
    );
    $formDecoration = array(
        'FormElements',
        array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'table', 'class'=>'forms')),
        'Form'
    );

    // create form elements
    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("username");
    $username->setLabel('Username: ')
             ->setDecorators($elementDecoration);

    $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password("password");
    $password->setLabel('Password: ')
             ->setDecorators($elementDecoration);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Login');
    $submit->setLabel('LOGIN')
           ->setDecorators($buttonDecoration);

    $this->setDecorators($formDecoration);

    // set created form elements
    $this->setAction('')
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->addElement($username)
        ->addElement($password)
        ->addElement($submit);
    }

   }
```

Comment: you did not validate nor vote for the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you only require to add `<td class="fieldTip"></td>`, or if you need to add things inside the `<td></td>`.

In the first case you just need to add a simple HtmlTag decorator right after the Label decorator :

```
array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'fieldTip','placement'=> 'APPEND'))
```

If you want to put some sort of description of the field you should play with the Description decorator, and the $element->setDescription() method, and do some css/js after, to display it as a tooltip.

**EDIT**

I just answered an other question about simple custom decorators, you'll find what you need in the example i give there [Zend Form Element with Javascript - Decorator, View Helper or View Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468548/947390). Just replace the `<script>` part with whatever you need.

Comment: I need to put some content into <td></td> tags, and I already have description bellow Zend_Form_Element, I need something like another description.... 
anyway, I will use your example and set up content in <td> tag by JavaScript

Comment: That's it! Thanks, 

I will give vote up on answer, when I get 15 reputation :)

Comment: i think you've got your reputation now ;)